# How to decode POST data from github in web.py?

Tags: python, json, web-services, github, web.py

(This question is related - but not the same - to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740353/how-to-convert-a-string-data-to-a-json-object-in-python) one)

This is the POST data that I get from a github hook:

```
payload=%7B%22pusher%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22none%22%7D%2C%22repository%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22size%22%3A84%2C%22has_wiki%22%3Atrue%2C%22created_at%22%3A%222012%2F01%2F12%2001%3A04%3A25%20-0800%22%2C%22watchers%22%3A1%2C%22private%22%3Afalse%2C%22fork%22%3Afalse%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgonvaled%2Ftest%22%2C%22pushed_at%22%3A%222012%2F01%2F12%2001%3A05%3A26%20-0800%22%2C%22has_downloads%22%3Atrue%2C%22open_issues%22%3A0%2C%22has_issues%22%3Atrue%2C%22homepage%22%3A%22%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22%22%2C%22forks%22%3A1%2C%22owner%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22gonvaled%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22gonvaled%40gonvaled.com%22%7D%7D%2C%22forced%22%3Afalse%2C%22after%22%3A%2214209371dcbdd95cc3ef5c4a07d80edd42f1295c%22%2C%22deleted%22%3Afalse%2C%22ref%22%3A%22refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster%22%2C%22commits%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22before%22%3A%2214209371dcbdd95cc3ef5c4a07d80edd42f1295c%22%2C%22compare%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgonvaled%2Ftest%2Fcompare%2F1420937...1420937%22%2C%22created%22%3Afalse%7D
```

Which I can decode using this:

```
urllib.unquote(data)
```

Getting this:

```
payload={"pusher":{"name":"none"},"repository":{"name":"test","size":84,"has_wiki":true,"created_at":"2012/01/12 01:04:25 -0800","watchers":1,"private":false,"fork":false,"url":"https://github.com/gonvaled/test","pushed_at":"2012/01/12 01:05:26 -0800","has_downloads":true,"open_issues":0,"has_issues":true,"homepage":"","description":"","forks":1,"owner":{"name":"gonvaled","email":"gonvaled@gonvaled.com"}},"forced":false,"after":"14209371dcbdd95cc3ef5c4a07d80edd42f1295c","deleted":false,"ref":"refs/heads/master","commits":[],"before":"14209371dcbdd95cc3ef5c4a07d80edd42f1295c","compare":"https://github.com/gonvaled/test/compare/1420937...1420937","created":false}
```

I can see the JSON there, after the `payload=` bit. The question I have is: what format is the full data? How can I get just the payload bit, using standard python libraries; I would prefer to avoid splitting the string myself, since I do not know the special cases.

The [github help page](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/) gives this suggested implementation for a Sinatra server:

```
post '/' do
  push = JSON.parse(params[:payload])
  "I got some JSON: #{push.inspect}"
end
```

How can this `params` array be handled in python, with standard libraries? What is the most pythonic implementation of that Ruby code? My end goal is to have the full POST data accessible as a python dictionary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a string data to a JSON object in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740353/how-to-convert-a-string-data-to-a-json-object-in-python)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate (by the way, I have linked to *exactly* that question in mine). The other question has no `payload=` prefix to the JSON data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json
import urlparse
data = urlparse.parse_qs(r)
print json.loads(r['payload'][0])
```

where `r` is the string you received as response.

See http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs

Comment: This is _very_ ad-hoc, and not at all what I am looking for. I do not want to process this specific POST data (I actually want, but this is not the point). I want to *learn* how to access POST parameters in python.

Comment: I thought you are interested more on interpreting the json part. I changed the code to parse the query string.

Comment: Also, parse_qs does the unquoting for you, so there is no need to pass the data through urllib.unquote.

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Just a note: for python 2.5, parse_qs is in module cgi.

Answer (score 2):

```
import urlparse
import json
s = "payload=%7B%22pusher%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22none%22%7D%2C%22repository%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22size%22%3A84%2C%22has_wiki%22%3Atrue%2C%22created_at%22%3A%222012%2F01%2F12%2001%3A04%3A25%20-0800%22%2C%22watchers%22%3A1%2C%22private%22%3Afalse%2C%22fork%22%3Afalse%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgonvaled%2Ftest%22%2C%22pushed_at%22%3A%222012%2F01%2F12%2001%3A05%3A26%20-0800%22%2C%22has_downloads%22%3Atrue%2C%22open_issues%22%3A0%2C%22has_issues%22%3Atrue%2C%22homepage%22%3A%22%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22%22%2C%22forks%22%3A1%2C%22owner%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22gonvaled%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22gonvaled%40gonvaled.com%22%7D%7D%2C%22forced%22%3Afalse%2C%22after%22%3A%2214209371dcbdd95cc3ef5c4a07d80edd42f1295c%22%2C%22deleted%22%3Afalse%2C%22ref%22%3A%22refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster%22%2C%22commits%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22before%22%3A%2214209371dcbdd95cc3ef5c4a07d80edd42f1295c%22%2C%22compare%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgonvaled%2Ftest%2Fcompare%2F1420937...1420937%22%2C%22created%22%3Afalse%7D"
L = urlparse.parse_qsl(s)
for k, v in L:
    print k
    print json.loads(v)
```

gives

```
payload
{u'forced': False, u'compare': u'https://github.com/gonvaled/...1420937', ... 
 u'before': u'14209371dcbdd95cc3ef5c4a07d80edd42f1295c'}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned *twice* in my question, I would like to parse the POST parameters with *standard* libraries, and not split it ad-hoc. There must be an accepted way of walking all parameters in a POST  request in python, one of which, `payload` - the only one in my case - has incidentally JSON data. Please note that I do not have questions related to decoding of the JSON data, just on how to get the different parameters of the POST request.

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding the question. `urlparse.parse_qsl` returns a list of (key, json-encoded value) that I hope is what you're after.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my comment that I've edited my answer accordingly.